# Как в питоне сделать бесконечный многомерный массив

Tags: python

Как в питоне сдалась так, что во время работы пользователя в двумерный массив добавлялся ещё массив и получался трёхмерный массив.

Например:

```
A=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3,]]
```

И потом:

```
А=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3,],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: для справки: список, содержащий три списка __не является__ трехмерным массивом. Ответ на вопрос: `A.append([4,5,6])`

Comment: В Python нет многомерных массивов. Если Вы подразумеваете список списков, то используйте метод `append`.

Comment: А как именно создать новый массив в массиве ? Можно пример ?

Comment: `A.append([4,5,6])` - добавит список к списку списков

Comment: @nomnoms12, почему нет? `[[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]],
 [[12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]]]` - трехмерная матрица размерности `(2,3,4)`

Comment: @MaxU Ну потому что пример, который Вы привели - это список списков :). Многомерный массив - это отдельная структура данных. Её нет в Python, в отличие от некоторых других ЯП.

Comment: @nomnoms12, это список списков списков, чем, грубо говоря, является 3D матрица